# detect roaming events?

Tags: android

How could I detect that the phone is data roaming ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the isNetworkRoaming() function from TelephonyManager to find this out

Comment: Is this function returning true whether data roaming or voice roaming ? To me the documentation is confusing : "Returns true if the device is considered roaming on the current network, for GSM purposes. "

Comment: whats the difference between the two? If you are on a roaming network you will be both on data as well as voice roaming. Is there any case where you can be on one and not on the other?

Comment: I'd agree on Prashast answer and comment. Nice answer!

Comment: Is that always true?  Do you know how every provider, all over the world, works?  You're absolutely certain that no one has something like a service where voice is considered not roaming, and data is considered roaming, on the same sim/account?  Really certain?  How do you plan to test that assumption?  How do you plan to guarantee that that assumption is still true next month?